# Does anyone knows a REST based CSS minifier?

Tags: css, api, rest, minify

I have a handler that needs to read the content of a CSS file, and then output the content minified.

So thats why I'm looking for a minifier that would work as a REST api, so I can send content, and get back the response to output this content to the user. 
Something like the [Closure compiler REST service](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-CA/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_api.html), but for CSS.

Comment: Seeing as this question is better worded than the one before, and the other one was downvoted beyond salvation, I vote for letting this one live. Although I'm not sure I grasp the point of a specifically REST based CSS minifier

Comment: Can you explain why you need a REST based minifier?

Comment: Well thank you Pekka !
Ashok, I need it REST based because I will call it from inside my .net handler. As you can see, Google provides a REST based service for their Javascript Closure compiler (see link above). So, I was wondering if anyone knows a REST service that does a minification process of a CSS file.

Comment: Why not use any other server-side minifier? Why REST?

Comment: No can't do madhead. Needs to be a service, REST is the best, but it can be a standard service.

Comment: [.Maui](https://dotmaui.com/) is awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/minify-shrink-javascript-and-css-with.html) (http://reducisaurus.appspot.com/css?url=YOUR_CSS_FILE_URL). Not actually a web service, but very close. [Googlecode](http://code.google.com/p/reducisaurus/)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Exactly what I was looking for ! As you say, it's not a web service, but I can call a GET on this within my handler. It's going to work perfectly ! Thanks !

Comment: I am still curious of your handler logic. You have external CSS (on other site, maybe) and you want to compress it and send to the client? :)

Comment: Kinda. I have a handler in front of a static file server (ie: js & css files). Requests come from a website to this handler, with in querystring the requested file. Handler process the request: reads the content of the file, apply minification on it (js file is optimized via rest api from Closure compiler, css file from reducisaurus) and sends back the result to client. The handler cache the response, and cache is invalided everytime the physical js or css file is changed. All this so we only have 1 version of the js/css file on server, not 2 version (minified & un-minified).

Answer (score 4):

Check this website - http://cssminifier.com/

They offer an API to use with POST requests

Comment: [.Muai](https://dotmaui.com/) has a API with great features!

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://cnvyr.io - also has bundling and image thumbnailing etc

Comment: Don't just post links, include the solution as links may change

Comment: Please look at the other posts before commenting on mine